# VBA to capture errors in a seperate excel instance

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have written a VBA procedure which opens, refreshes, saves and closes a large number of excel files containing pivot tables. The code loops through each report in turn, opening it up in a **separate excel instance** and refreshing it as well as other tasks. I have an error handler to capture errors produced if it can't find the file and if the file is read-only but I am trying to extend it capture errors which may be produced during the refresh/save steps.

The problem is that as these errors occur in the "Refresh instance" of Excel whilst the errorhandler is in the "Control instance" of Excel it doesn't catch them. Does anyone know how to catch errors in another excel instance?

```
Errorhandler:

errorText = StandardPivots(1, myIndex)
Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
failedIndex = failedIndex + 1
objXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
objXL.Quit

Resume Next
End Sub
```

**StandardPivots** is a variant which holds the reports to be refreshed.
**Failed** is a array string which will hold the list of errored files
**objXL** refers to my "Refresh Instance" of Excel

It needs to be in a separate Excel instance as I have a method where the user can shut down the process which needs to be accessible at all times (not locked like it would be if a file was refreshing)

Just in case it's useful. Here is how I handle the errors at the end:

```
If failedIndex = 0 Then
   OutputMsg = "All " & RefreshType & " Pivots Refreshed"
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Range("E25").Value = OutputMsg 'Just in case e-mail process fails, pivots which failed are output to excel
   Produce_Email
Else
    For x = 0 To failedIndex - 1
    OutputMsg = OutputMsg + Failed(x) & ", "
    Next x
OutputMsg = Left(OutputMsg, Len(OutputMsg) - 2)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Range("E25").Value = OutputMsg
Produce_Email ' Main module
```

Let me know if you need anything else from me?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Short answer is that you can't - error handling is per process. What about just adding a custom property to `ThisWorkbook` that allows you to request the error count\items from the "Refresh Instance" after it completes?

Comment: Well that's annoying but thanks for confirming that. Can you explain how I'd go about requesting the error count\items from the Refresh instance please?